# Automatic Reload is Not Working in React Js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, webpack-dev-server

[I am unable to see any update on my web page. because when I use `npm start` then it shows compile with one error. and my webpack-dev-server is not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2IN7.png)

Comment: Maybe you're importing a module in your app that doesn't exist.

Comment: just out of curiosity, what is "Recat" ?, and second... are you running the project in windows from WSL ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to check in your folder structure that any folder name includes special variables like (@,$,!,#,%,^,&,*) or any Spaces. if yes then rename fonder name with proper name.